# Reactor: download n images in parallel and failure of one shouldn't affect the rest

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a use case where I want to fetch image paths (through n REST calls). I want these calls to run in parallel and failure of one shouldn't affect the rest.

This is what i have tried, but the problem is that the calls run sequentially:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.elastic();
Flux.fromIterable(product.getIds()).runOn(scheduler)
                     .map(item -> getImages(item))
                      .subscribe(img -> System.out.println(img));
```

I have been trying it in Spring webflux. Any thoughts on what I am missing here?

Comment: can you add the request client code(getImages method)? requests are probably blocking

Comment: Can you please post the correct code? `runOn` is only available on `ParallelFlux`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parallel()` to turn `Flux` that emits items sequentially into `ParallelFlux`.

```
Flux.fromIterable(product.getIds())
  .parallel()
  .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
  .map(item -> getImages(item))
  .subscribe(img -> System.out.println(img));
```